# Unable to find custom modules for Suite CRM using CDATA

Tags: java, sql, cdata, suitecrm

When i query for foreign keys for a table in for Suitecrm using CData queries, I get referencedTableName as FP_Event_Locations. When search for FP_Event_Locations under tables, I don't see it.
I tired googling and didn't find answer yet. These are custom modules added by Suite Crm, What is the way to fetch these tables.

Answer (score 0):

The actual table name is specified in the module Class.
For any module in SuiteCRM you can go to the `modules` folder and search for the module you are looking for.

In your case that will be `modules/FP_Event_Locations/`.

Inside the folder there is the module definition file usually named exactly like the module name with/without a `_sugar` prefix.

If you check this file 
`modules/FP_Event_Locations/FP_Event_Locations_sugar.php`

you will see the table name, in your case `fp_event_locations`

```
 class FP_Event_Locations_sugar extends Basic {
    var $new_schema = true;
    var $module_dir = 'FP_Event_Locations';
    var $object_name = 'FP_Event_Locations';
    var $table_name = 'fp_event_locations';
    var $importable = false;
```

Comment: For foreign keys i use the below CDATA query " boolean ret = stat.execute("SELECT * FROM sys_keycolumns WHERE IsForeignKey='True' AND TableName='Work Order'");"  Is there a query through which i can find out all system modules.

Comment: there are a few tables that contains module information but ain't reliable and foreignkeys in the suitecrm are not yet reliable (vardefs foreignkey doesn't work)